# jQuery Error - Cannot use 'in' operator to search for

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This worked before, but now gives the error after deploying. 
There are two dropdownlists. Selecting a value in the first one, will get some data from server and bind it to the second. I get this error in browser console after selecting a value in the first drop down.

What could be going wrong.

**JS:**

```
var modelsList = [];
    function GetModels(cId, bId, selectedIds) {
        modelsList = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "/_layouts/handlers/Smarts.ashx",
            //type: "GET",
            data: { 'cId': cId, 'bId': bId, 'selectedIds': selectedIds },
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {                                
                $(".ddlModels").empty();
                var items = "<option value=\"0\">Select Model</option>";
                $.each(msg, function () {
                    var objModel = {};
                    objModel["HId"] = this.HId;
                    objModel["BrandName"] = this.BrandName;
                    modelsList.push(objModel);
           items += "<option value=\"" + this.HId + "\">" + this.BrandName+ "</option>";
                });
                $(".ddlModels").html(items);
                $(".ddlModels").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                $(".selectedModel").html("Select Model");
            },
            error: function () {                
                alert("An error occurred while processing your request");
            }
        });
    }
```

**ASHX:**

```
public static List<Model> GetModels(int cId, int bId, string selectedIds)
    {
List<Model> lstModels = new List<Model>();
//function to get data
return lstModels;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are seeing? You reference getting an error, but without the error text, it's hard to know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If it gives the error, I assume you are referring to the error of the Ajax request:

`alert("An error occurred while processing your request");`

This means the Ajax request itself failed. That points you in the right direction.

Now two possible problems come to mind:
1. The destination is no longer available (routing or destination changed)
2. GetModels doesn't return a response.

In all honestly. You should include more debugging information

Comment: Not referring to error of ajax request. Its the error that shows up in browser console after selecting a value in dropdwon1. GetModels is fired after selecting a value in dropdown1

Comment: Unless you provide more information to help people answer your question better, it isn't worth answering.

Nobody can run your code, so it would be very helpfull to know:
1. Where it occurs (Which you just told me)
2. What values of variables can we expect (Not always needed)
3. The error you are getting